# Why is my padding left not being removed with last-child?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

No matter what i try the padding-right cant be removed using lastchild i tried using imglastchild then lilastchild also last-of-type.

```
 <div class="Social_Media">
        <ul>
        <li><img src="Social/facebook.png"></li>
        <li><img src="Social/twitter.png"></li>
        <li><img src="Social/youtube.png"></li>
        <li><img src="Social/googleplus.png"></li>
        <li><img src="Social/linked.png"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

 .Social_Media ul{
padding-top:10px;
float:right;}

.Social_Media li{
display:inline;}


    .Social_Media img{
    padding-right:25px;
    background-color:red;
}
.Social_media img:last-child {
     padding-right:0px
}
```

Comment: Please fix the syntax errors on your CSS. The first two rules are missing a `}`. Plus your last selector `.Social_media` has a typo.

Comment: I just removed these by mistake while pasting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple typos in the code you posted (see my comment above), however the real issue is that you're selecting the wrong element. Your final selector should be

```
.Social_Media li:last-child img {
    padding-right:0px
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bddrmzyn/1/)**

You need to select the last *list item* with `:last-child` and then the image within it and remove the padding. Using `:last-child` on the image would actually apply to every image in your example as they're all the last child of their parent container.